# converting my inner join sql statement EXISTS

Tags: sql

I thought that the following statements would produce the same results... but they don't. The first code including the 'exists' statement doesn't seem to be limiting the selected value by the 'QuizID' column I thought it should... as a side note this column only exists in 'quizQuestions' but not in 'quizAnswers'

```
SELECT qa.QuestionNumber 
FROM QuizAnswers qa 
where exists (SELECT * 
              FROM QuizQuestions 
              WHERE QUIZID = 6)
```

```
SELECT qa.QuestionNumber 
FROM QuizAnswers qa 
   INNER JOIN QuizQuestions IQQ 
      ON qa.QuestionNumber = IQQ.QuestionNumber
WHERE QUIZID = 6
```

The statement including the 'inner join' contains the result set that I want..
What do I need to include in my Exists statement in order to get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your `EXISTS` query is doing is selecting all question numbers when there exists a row in the `QuizQuestions` table that has a `QUIZID` of `6`. If there is a row, it will select all question numbers, otherwise, it will select none. What you need to do is make it ***correlated*** with the outer query so that it is dependent on each `QuestionNmber`...

You need to put `AND QuestionNumber = qa.QuestionNumber` as a second condition in the `EXISTS` to make it a correlated subquery.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me clear up some misconceptions i had about Exists, especially your edit.

Answer (score 2):

This query

```
SELECT qa.QuestionNumber FROM QuizAnswers qa where exists ( SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions WHERE QUIZID = 6)
```

is equivalent to this

```
SELECT qa.QuestionNumber FROM QuizAnswers qa
```

if there is anything in QuizQuestions with QuizID = 6.  See Zane's answer for the solution to this, depending on your SQL implementation, it's usually a better idea to go with the INNER JOIN version regardless.

Comment: If this is a commentary on another answer, rather than its own answer, why not use the comments section?  *(Also the INNER JOIN version is not so good in 1:many relationship, where as EXISTS will maintain the 1: part of the 1:many.)*

Comment: @dfb thanks, i was going for making the select statement into a delete statement once i got the correct.  It just makes more sense to me if i have an exists statement.  This helps clarity zanes answer as well.